# this.refs vs value in react for form usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How would you guys do a form submission? I have no problem making a form but I saw 2 different approach. Personally I use state to bind the form value

```
<input onChange={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.username} type="text" name="username" />
```

to get the input value I will do this

```
handleInputChange = () => (
   const username = e.target.username.value;
)
```

It worked but not sure this is a good approach, another approach is using refs.

The good thing is no need to put onChange on every fields, in onSubmit simply do this

```
this.refs.username.value
```

and you have ur element like this `<input ref="username" type="text" />`

But how to set the value of the username if the initial load is an ajax?

Comment: you can use defaultValue to set initial value when you want to access the value by ref

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to not use refs unless you have no other way of doing things. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Your approach with binding the value to state seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about using the onChange(one-way binding) is that you have full control over the input data.

Say if you want input to have only alphabets

```
handleInputChange = () => (
   // you can have validation code here to check if the 
   // input has only alphabets and return if otherwise 
   const username = e.target.username.value;
)
```

Comment: imagine you have 10 fields, you have to have 10 different handler?